# What is the range of possible sha1hash results?

Tags: algorithm, hash, cryptography, sha

What is the lowest and highest possible returns from sha1? (with respect that sha1 results are actualy 5 32 bit values rather than 1 true 160 bit value)

Comment: The question would be more suited on 
[Crypto Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It doesn't matter that SHA-1 treats its 160 bits as 32 bit words. I don't think we have proof that every output value is reachable, but we certainly expect them to be.

Comment: @CodesInChoas - it's not that it treats a true 160 bit value as 5 32 bit words, it's that it builds 5 unsigned 32 bit numbers and treats it as 160 bits. Its the same as using 4 unsigned 8 bit numbers and expecting all the possibe values of a true 32 bit number type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a secure hash the output of the hash must be indistinguishable from random. Many *pseudo* random number generators and key derivation methods actually use a hash as final calculation.

So the "highest" result consists of all zero's, the lowest consists of all ones. That is, if you *interpret* the result to be an unsigned integer of course. The chances of exactly getting those values is almost zero of course, as SHA-1 results should be evenly distributed. But the change of a number starting with 8 ones is still `1/2^8` == `1/256`, which is certainly not insignificant.

Note that the result of SHA-1 should be interpreted as a bit string. Most runtimes don't have a very useful bitstring representation and use an octet string (aka byte array) instead. I would consider it very annoying of a SHA-1 implementation would return shorts instead of bytes. You don't want to annoy the user with differences in little-endian and big-endian representations, and most other primitives do expect their input represented as bytes.

Comment: So for shorts, you should expect the full range of values for your specific runtime.